# Yii Письмо приходит пользователю без тега ссылки <a>

Tags: yii, email, phpmailer

С сайта отправляются письма подтверждения регистрации в html. И все бы ничего, но появилось несколько пользователей, у которых ссылки в письме нет. То есть вместо тега Подтвердить там только "Подтвердить". Не могу понять чем отличаются эти пользователи и как сделать, чтобы подобного не повторялось???
Для справки - у этих необычных пользователей браузеры Edge и Opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые email клиенты могут резать html теги. Лучшее указать саму ссылку вместо "Подтвердить", так почти все делают. Или хотя бы указать ссылку в виде текста где-то ниже.